# gstreamer ios undefined symbol _gst_plugin_liveadder_register

Tags: ios, gstreamer

I have tried to compile the gstreamer ios tutorial #3. I have built the iOS SDK from sources that I have checked out from git, the master tree, and then when I have tried to compile for iOS 9.2. I got the below link error which I have no explanation for. All help is much appreciated.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_gst_plugin_liveadder_register", referenced from:
  _gst_ios_init in gst_ios_init.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: From where did you get the tutorials? But indeed, if you got them from my GIT repository then the gst_ios_main.[hm] files have to updated for 1.6+. Which GStreamer version are you using?