# missing symbols in Gstreamer IOS tutorial

Tags: ios, gstreamer

I have just downloaded the gstreamer ios binaries from https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/ios/1.8.1/.  and the gstreamer sdk from https://cgit.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials/ (which has not been updated for 7 months? -- is there a newer version)?

When I enable the following features in gst_ios_init.h, i am unable to resolve the symbols as follows.  Is there a newer SDK?  I don't need liveadder or fragmented or editing tools, but the ios compression support seems like it would be useful.

When I enable:

```
#define GST_IOS_PLUGINS_EFFECTS
```

I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gst_plugin_liveadder_register", referenced from:
      _gst_ios_init in gst_ios_init.o
```

When I enable:

```
#define GST_IOS_PLUGINS_CODECS
```

I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gst_plugin_fragmented_register", referenced from:
      _gst_ios_init in gst_ios_init.o
```

When I enable:

```
#define GST_IOS_PLUGINS_EDITING
```

I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gst_plugin_gnonlin_register", referenced from:
      _gst_ios_init in gst_ios_init.o
```

When I enable:

```
#define GST_IOS_PLUGINS_SYS
```

I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_VTCompressionSessionCompleteFrames", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_finish in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_VTCompressionSessionCreate", referenced from:
      _plugin_init in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-plugin.o)
      _gst_vtenc_set_format in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_handle_frame in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_VTCompressionSessionInvalidate", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_destroy_session in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_VTCompressionSessionPrepareToEncodeFrames", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_set_format in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_VTDecompressionSessionCreate", referenced from:
      _gst_vtdec_negotiate in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtdec.o)
  "_VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame", referenced from:
      _gst_vtdec_handle_frame in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtdec.o)
  "_VTDecompressionSessionInvalidate", referenced from:
      _gst_vtdec_invalidate_session in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtdec.o)
  "_VTDecompressionSessionWaitForAsynchronousFrames", referenced from:
      _gst_vtdec_push_frames_if_needed in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtdec.o)
  "_VTSessionCopyProperty", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_handle_frame in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
      _gst_vtenc_session_dump_property in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_VTSessionCopySupportedPropertyDictionary", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_set_format in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_VTSessionSetProperty", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_set_property in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
      _gst_vtenc_set_format in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
      _gst_vtenc_session_configure_property_double in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
      _gst_vtenc_session_configure_property_int in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AllowFrameReordering", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_set_property in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
      _gst_vtenc_set_format in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AllowTemporalCompression", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_set_format in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AverageBitRate", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_set_property in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
      _gst_vtenc_set_format in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_kVTCompressionPropertyKey_ExpectedFrameRate", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_set_format in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxKeyFrameInterval", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_set_property in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
      _gst_vtenc_set_format in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxKeyFrameIntervalDuration", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_set_property in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
      _gst_vtenc_set_format in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_kVTCompressionPropertyKey_NumberOfPendingFrames", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_handle_frame in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_kVTCompressionPropertyKey_ProfileLevel", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_set_format in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_kVTCompressionPropertyKey_Quality", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_set_quality in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_kVTCompressionPropertyKey_RealTime", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_set_property in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
      _gst_vtenc_set_format in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
  "_kVTEncodeFrameOptionKey_ForceKeyFrame", referenced from:
      _gst_vtenc_init in GStreamer(libgstapplemedia_a_x86_64_-libgstapplemedia_la-vtenc.o)
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127066/gstreamer-ios-undefined-symbol-gst-plugin-liveadder-register) seems to be similar

Comment: Have you found the answer? I have a similar issue!

Comment: the sdk tutorials typically contain a gst_ios_init.m file.  in this file, all the static gstreamer functions are declared.  if you comment out the section for the liveadder element and the section for the fragmented element, you should make some progress.  these elements are not provided in the current built gstreamer ios sdk.

Comment: i have same error when i uncomment "#define GST_IOS_PLUGINS_CODECS" i got error   "_gst_plugin_schro_register", referenced from:

Answer (score 1):

Just add VideoToolBox framework to your project.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `gstreamer` framework installed is not the same as the tutorial. Copy according `gst_ios_init.h` and `gst_ios_init.m` to tutorial project will fix the issue